# SQL query to determine if there are any artists that are not associated with a track

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Please help with this question:
Write an appropriate SQL query to determine if there are any artists that are not associated with a track. I have to use a SELECT, JOIN AND WHERE clause.
Sample results:

```
ARTIST_ID  ARTIST_NAME
----------------------
AR011      Elvis Presley
```

This is how my table looks like:

```
ARTIST_ID  ARTIST_NAME    TRACK_ID  TRACK_NAME  TRACK_DURATION
------------------------------------------------------------
AR001      Marshmallow    TR001     Silence     3.5
AR002      Khalid         TR001     Silence     3.5
AR003      The Script     TR001     Silence     3.5
AR004      Sam Smiths     TR001     Silence     3.5
AR005      Nick Jonas     TR001     Silence     3.5
AR006      Goldfish       TR001     Silence     3.5
AR007      Method         TR001     Silence     3.5
AR008      Justin Bieber  TR001     Silence     3.5
AR009      BloodPop       TR001     Silence     3.5
AR010      Pink           TR001     Silence     3.5
AR011      Elvis Presley  TR001     Silence     3.5
AR001      Marshmallow    TR002     Rain        4.0
AR002      Khalid         TR002     Rain        4.0
AR003      The Script     TR002     Rain        4.0
```

Comment: Perhaps need to provide more data and better data sample. Based on that one screenshot, every artist has a track.

Comment: @Sandra Guilep Zouaoui Zandeh, What do you mean?

Comment: Which relation database management system are you using ? And please provide your input and output data.

Comment: @Isolated, Yes I know but I don't understand what to do too based on that example.

Comment: Why do you list Elvis Pressley as an example? In your screenshot, he clearly has a track (TR001).  Maybe you have another table for ARTIST that you are not showing us? And if so, then you want to see if any artists in that artist table are not found in your tracks table.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. And I can't read that tiny image text. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: @jarlh, ok I'll remember that. I'm new here and new to coding :)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I couldn’t delete it and I had no idea the lecturer wouldn’t want it here :) so I chose to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use `NOT EXISTS` to test for the presence of tracks in the `ALBUM_TRACKS` table.

```
select * 
from ARTISTS a
where not exists(select 1
                 from ALBUM_TRACKS tr
                 where a.ARTIST_ID=tr.ARTIST_ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the DB structure you posted in the comments, it should be somethig like this:

```
SELECT a.ARTIST_ID,a.ARTIST_NAME
FROM ARTISTS AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRACK_ARTISTS AS ta ON ta.ARTIST_ID = a.ARTIST_ID
WHERE ta.ARTIST_ID IS NULL
```

This asumes that you are require to use a JOIN clause, as you stated in you question.

Using EXISTS is a better option if no output is required for the joined table, such as in this case.

Comment: Thank you. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to get your requested results

```
SELECT a.*
FROM artists a
LEFT OUTER JOIN album_tracks t ON a.artist_id =t.artist_id
WHERE t.artist_id IS NULL
```